# Need for thread_info structure in Linux 2.6 Kernel

Tags: linux, kernel, process

Prior to the Linux 2.6 kernel, `struct task_struct` was present at the end of the kernel stack of each process. There was no `thread_info struct` concept. But in Linux 2.6 kernel, instead of `task_struct` being placed at the end of the kernel stack for the process, the `thread_info struct` is placed at the end. This thread_info struct contains a pointer to the `task_struct` structure.

What was the need for `thread_info` structure to be introduced ?. We could have accessed the `task_struct` structure using the `stack pointer` directly if `task_struct` was placed at the end of the kernel stack of the process.

In 2.6 Kernel, `task_struct` is dynamically allocated using `slab_allocator`. Prior to 2.6 Kernel, was it statically allocated?

Comment: Try searching for an explanation on [LWN](http://lwn.net/). Most major kernel changes get an explanatory write-up on LWN.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure why this was done. But it'd be easy to find it out if you do a `git blame` on that file and find the commit that introduced the change. Usually commit message will have very detailed explanation of the change being committed.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why we need the **thread_info** is due to the fact that we are allocating the memory for **task_struct** using the **Slab Allocator**. Now you may ask what is the relation between these?

To understand that you need to understand how Slab Allocator works.

Without the Slab Allocator , the kernel developers could allocate memory for task_struct in the kernel stack for the particular process so that it can be accessed easily. Now with the advent of Slab Allocator , the memory is allocated to the task_struct as determined by the Slab Allocator. So with the Slab Allocator you have task_struct stored somewhere else and not in the kernel stack of the particular process. Now the Kernel developers introduced thread_info and placed a pointer in it to the place where the task_struct resides. Thus we have **thread_info** in process's kernel stack instead of **task_struct**. And that is why we have to live with thread_info.

You can read about Slab Allocator in Robert Love's book Linux Kernel Development.